# Trigger Click on Select Element

Tags: jquery, css, select, triggers

Im building a custom select dropdown, which includes a custom dropdown arrow. Since the browser default arrow is covered by the custom arrow, im using `pointer-events: none;` in css, to allow for a click on the select behind the custom button. However, `pointer-events: none;` is not supported by IE 10 & below.

Ive written this code

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.select-dropdown-arrow', function() { 
      $(this).siblings('select').trigger('mousedown');
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

to trigger a click on the select and open the dropdown, but it is not working. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a horrible idea, if you want to build a custom dropdown, use an ordered or unordered list, and style it and make it work like a dropdown. Using a select with options will only cause you to loose all your hair.

Comment: Ive already completed the custom dropdown. Just need functionality in IE. Thanks.

Comment: I also failed to mention that this fix is only needed for IE. Chrome and Firefox don't necessarily need the script.

Comment: pointer-events works perfectly in my version of IE (11.0.9600.17239), just update your browser :)

Comment: Yes your correct, they work perfectly in IE11. But as I mentioned in the initial question, they don't work in versions before that. I am developing an app that requires support on multiple versions of IE, so if anyone has an helpful answer please advise. Otherwise please avoid commenting. Thanks.

Comment: See if mousedown function comes before the "$(document).on('click', '.select-dropdown-arrow', function() {"

Comment: @JoaoPaulo can you be more specific?

Comment: "$(document).on("mousedown", ".xxxx", function(){" needs to become first the "$(document).on('click', '.select-dropdown-arrow', function() { $(this).siblings('select').trigger('mousedown');" to work

Comment: @JoaoPaulo,
Maybe provide a sample. Im still not sure what you mean. to do mousdown in place of 'click' wont change anything I don't think. My current function is hitting the sibling, 'select' - as tested with an alert(). but .trigger('mousedown') is not working.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of testing and research, I was unable to find an adequate solution that offered support across all browsers, specifically IE. Overall, it seems that JS doesn't offer a clean/concise way to dynamically open a select dropdown via click of another element on the page.

Best solution is either to create a custom dropdown with an unordered list, or provide an alternate experience for unsupported browsers.

[Here is a resource I found](http://red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/custom-html-dropdown.html) regarding custom selects in general.